# Visual Studio Express 2012 Won't Install Win7

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have tried to install visual studio when i run wdexpress_full.exe it opens up but it does not do anything.

http://pastebin.com/SuSsZS8E

Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install with admin mode, Some times it is in users mode. Try to install with admin mode, right click on setup and choose run as administrator.

Comment: I am a administrator i even tried run as a administrator still nothing